# How to connect to a dev phone and gain the root permission through "adb shell"

Tags: android, adb, android-2.2-froyo

I'm using a dev phone (Nexus One). I connected to it through "adb shell" but I couldn't get the root permission. When I run "su" in the shell, I got

```
$ su
su: permission denied
```

Actually I cannot access "/sbin" at all.

When I used the "root" option in "adb", I got errors too:

```
./adb root -s xxx shell
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
```

I got this error no matter I used a downloaded SDK or I compiled an SDK from the source. I'm not sure about what "*production builds*" actually means. Does it mean that I need to compile Android and put it on the phone? I thought a dev phone already has the root permission unlocked.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: forum.xda-developers.com might be a much better place to post this question

Comment: if that is the case, then honestly we need a stackexchange just for questions like this.  that site has the least professional, hardest to understand posts i have ever seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should unlock your phone - root it. Nexus One comes with this option, but you have to enable it. You can read [this](http://androidandme.com/2010/01/hacks/video-how-to-unlock-and-root-a-nexus-one/) article or google for more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew I could root it, but somehow I thought a dev phone is supposed to be rooted out of the box. Apparently I was wrong.

Comment: @evergreen You can read first the manual, because in many cases rooting the phone voids the waranty, but if you read tutorials in the net, you can find a way to unroot your phone too.

Comment: @Michael how are you trying to get root?